# Service Discovery using chef recipe

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-solo, configuration-management

I am working on clustered environment, where I have multiple clusters with each cluster have multiple nodes involved. 
I have to announce the node the service is up and the master node have to discover the the newly available node.

I am announcing a new node as soon as it becomes available and search the node using chef search resource. I am using open source/ on premises chef-server, there seems to issue with the same. The results are ambiguous and not consistent too.

what is the alternate ways to achieve this, kindly help me out.

Thank you

Comment: Consul, etcd, zookeeper. Chef isnt made for short-term updates across cluster nodes.

Comment: what's ambiguous about the results you get from search?  That strategy should work just fine if you can afford the wait time between a new node registering and the next chef-client run on the master.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick solutions from top of my head:

- If you are in a windows environment, you can use Active Directory, the new nodes are joining to the domain, you can ask the domain for new instances.
- You can do the same with AWS tags. If you tag your instances well and your master node is able to query your instances by tags, you can filter for the actual service.
- Your new instances can put a message into SQS queues. The master nodes frequently pulling the queue. ( Each service can have it's own.)